# Xamarin Studio, GTK 2.0 C# application, runtime error, can't load libglib-2.0-0.dll

Tags: c#, windows, mono, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I've installed fresh Xamarin Studio 5.10 on Windows 7 and created standard GTK 2.0 C# project (via New Project > .Net > GTK#2.0 Project).

Code's below:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace _test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init ();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            win.Show ();
            Application.Run ();
        }
    }
}
```

Build is ok, but runtime error raises (I've translated error from my native language into english):

> Can't load DLL "libglib-2.0-0.dll": Procedure was not found (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

Mono and gtk# seems to be installed ok via exes from [official mono site](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win). Test console app works ok.

May anybody help :) ?

Comment: Is this error from the command line or running it from within Xamarin Studio?

Comment: From studio. The line Application.Init is highlighted with green and dialog "System.DllNotFoundException has been trown" is poped up...

Comment: I've completely reinstalled mono, gtk# and xamarin studio, it's all the same

Answer (score 6):

You need to reboot. 
I just had the same problem and that was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as the discussion topic points too, but I found the solution.

You might not select the .NET Runtimes as the Mono.
You can see what .NET Runtimes is selected in **Tools - Options - Projects - .NET Runtimes**. There you can change the .NET Runtimes.

If you find only **Microsoft.NET**, you should get latest Mono at mono-project.com and install it. You will be able to select Mono Runtime.

Following post is very helpful.

[How to debug in Xamarin Studio using mono runtime on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949137/how-to-debug-in-xamarin-studio-using-mono-runtime-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in the following setup:

- Windows Server 2012
- Gtk# for .Net 2.12.38
- Mono for Windows (x64) 4.3.2
- Xamarin Studio 5.10.1

I replaced `Gtk# for .Net 2.12.38` with `Gtk# for .Net 2.12.30` which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install the gtk sharp from https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ and the download link is https://xamarin.azureedge.net/GTKforWindows/Windows/gtk-sharp-2.12.45.msi

And then you should copy your gtk sharp dll to your output path.

Opening the `C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin` folder and copy the `libglib-2.0-0.dll` file to your output path.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens directly after you install GTKSharp for windows, restart Visual Studio.

Reason : the installer adds registry/environment variables and sometimes you need to restart either the Visual Studio or the PC.